# React apps have stopped working on Github Pages - 404 Error

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

My React Apps were working perfectly on Github Pages until a few days ago, now they are all giving me 404 errors.

I'm not sure what to try, I haven't changed anything so I'm not sure why they're suddenly not working.

Here is a link to an example: https://github.com/paulmartin91/WikiSearch

It used to host a wikipedia search page, but now I'm getting the following...

"
404
File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.

GitHub Status — @githubstatus
"

It is working locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fixed, I was using the github url 'https://github.com/paulmartin91/WikiSearch' as the package.json.homepage instead of the gh-pages url.